# How is it possible to write a BDP formula (Bloomberg) into an excel cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I want to write a Bloomberg formula in an excel cell with VBA. The formula, if written in the Cell directly "by hand", works as intended. I tried the following Code:

```
isin = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 37).Value.Formula = "=BDP(""" & isin & " ISIN"";""SHORT_NAME"")"
```

but I get an error 424 (object required).

If I try using only .Value or .Formula (I found a lot examples like this online) like:

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 37).Value = "=BDP(""" & isin & " ISIN"";""SHORT_NAME"")"
```

or

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 37).Formula = "=BDP(""" & isin & " ISIN"";""SHORT_NAME"")"
```

I get an error 1004 (Application-defined or Object-defined error)

Comment: Does `.FormulaLocal` instead of `.Formula` work?

Comment: Yea it works if using only FormulaLocal!
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 37).FormulaLocal = "=BDP(""" & isin & " ISIN"";""SHORT_NAME"")"
Thank you